# Can't import GLPK package in Python 3.6. Throws error ModuleNameNotFound

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, conda, glpk

I can successfully install GLPK package using conda install and it lists out on conda list but I can't seem to import it into Python. Can anyone help me out with that?

Comment: What is the module that you are trying to import?

Comment: Have you made sure that all the required software is installed? The library relies on other libraries both on Windows and Linux